# Do suspended moderators regain their moderator privileges?

Tags: discussion, moderators, suspension

Well in light of the recent fiasco which occured in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), it would seem atleast a moderator (I won't name names!) was suspended for, what I would assume, lack of "moderating".

**If a moderator was suspended and he/she returns after their allotted suspension, are they still a moderator?**

Comment: I don't think so. All four of [the SFF.SE moderators](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) are unsuspended and still have all their rep.

Comment: None of the three suspended users are moderators. One of them used to be a moderator, but none of them are anymore.

Comment: What Ixrec said.

Comment: I see, (you can tell I'm not an active member...).

Comment: From a technical standpoint, you can't suspend a diamond moderator. On Q&A sites, they can immediately unsuspend themselves. In chat, I'm 99% sure a suspension just doesn't do anything.

Comment: @AdamLear - Interesting, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As this is not the current situation,  I will answer this hypothetical situation - Moderator powers are unrelated to being suspended.

If said hypothetical moderator were to have taken actions worthy of being suspended, then I would imagine that their ability to moderate would be reviewed by the community management team and the remaining moderators at the least.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I was merely curious.

Comment: It's kinda tempting to suspend myself, for science.

Comment: @Keen Moderators suspending themselves has happened before ...

Comment: @Keen Just don't flag yourself, for science.

Comment: To clarify on this - moderators are actually incapable of being suspended. If there's a problem with a moderator that's independent of their powers as a moderator, then we simply reach out to them and try and talk through the situation. If it's directly related to moderator powers, then we'd temporarily revoke those powers and then do the talking stuffs so that, ideally, we can reinstate their powers without further issue.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, yea we already know how that science experiment ends...

Comment: @Keen pleeeez I want to see how it looks like :D